# Repository pattern in Laravel using Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel, repository-pattern

For a project at work I'm creating an API in Laravel. I wanted to use MongoDB as database driver which is new to me. So I want to use Eloquent with MySQL in the beginning and when I'm confident enough switch to MongoDB.

I was reading some tutorials about the repository pattern in Laravel and saw that some returned an eloquent model, like [this one](https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/). It seems to me that when returning a model on for example `create($data)`, you're limited to database drivers which are suitable with Eloquent. I was wondering if it is a good practice to return an eloquent model. Because if I want to use MySQL for now and in the future MongoDB (without the Laravel MongoDB package), I need to rewrite some code in the controllers because the use the eloquent models instead of an array (for example). Maybe a 'wrapper' between the model and your code is a possibility? Any good recommendations, tips or thoughts on this?

If you're wondering why I want to use MySQL for now and later switch to MongoDB, the reason is there is a time limit on the project. I'm still learning Mongo. So to fulfil the needs of my employer, I'm not using MongoDB until finishing the first version / prototype.

Comment: I don't really know anymore, big chunk why Laravel is so popular is because of Eloquent. And remark to the repository pattern you are just adding whole lot of fluff for nothing. Never use new tech for clients (employer), use something you are comfy/brave enough that will solve the problem, in this case stick with SQL kind of database and use drivers provided by Laravel itself. You can experiment with MongoDB in JavaScript world. Even now (before implementation itself) you are asking questions that no-one has answer for, stick to the "standards" and play on your own time. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you use eloquent and its methods, you should be good. Just do not use the `DB::raw()` method as it may break your query if it does not match the DB engine you are currently in.

I wrote a [repository pattern](https://medium.com/@jsdecena/refactor-the-simple-tdd-in-laravel-a92dd48f2cdd) article if you want to look at it (with tdd).

But if you really want future proof, you can mix Doctrine w Laravel since Doctrine is a Data Mapper Pattern. [Link](https://www.laraveldoctrine.org/)

With laravel-doctrine package, you persist the data in your db engine that you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like [laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) good?

Extending Eloquent to use MongoDB instead of MySQL.

Comment: Personally I don't have a great experience with that package. Eloquent is very powerful and specifically build to use something like MySQL. The package just doesn't work as smooth as the MySQL driver. But again, that's my personal experience.